# Given algorithm which prints $n$-th string of nested parentheses, find a reverse algorithm

Tags: permutations, catalan-numbers

We have the following balanced brackets permutations of length $4\cdot 2$ in lexicographical order:

```
1.  (((())))
2.  ((()()))
3.  ((())())
4.  ((()))()
5.  (()(()))
6.  (()()())
7.  (()())()
8.  (())(())
9.  (())()()
10. ()((()))
11. ()(()())
12. ()(())()
13. ()()(())
14. ()()()()
```

I tried an algorithm by Frank Ruskey found by user MJD  in Knuth's "The art of computer programming, volume 4A". However, it prints the $n$-th string from the end so I'd like to ask for a hint: how can I reverse the algorithm?

I know that I could just replace the argument $N$ with $C(n)-N$ but as $n<5000$ I'd have to use bignums to write the program and I believe it's unnecessary. Moreover, in that case I'd waste time for calculating $C(n)$ and Mr Ruskey invented the algorithm so that it wouldn't be necessary to calculate $C(x)$ every time as it's calculated at the beginning and modified in progress.

Here's an [explanation](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/Thesis/Thesis.html) of this algorithm. Note that there are $C(n)$ such strings (where $C(n)$ is the $n$-th Catalan number).

Comment: Is there some reason why you cannot make your $f(n) = g(C(k) - n)$, where $g$ is the Frank Ruskey algorithm?

Comment: Just replace $N$ by $C_n+1-N$ in the algorithm.

Comment: C(n) are humongous for n>100. And I'd have to use bignums to write such a program and I'm sure that can be avoided. I'm not that stupid, MJD and Brian. :-) But thank You for trying.

Comment: I don't understand this. Won't the typical argument to $f$ be on the same order as $C(k)$ anyway? If not, and you need $f(n)$ only for small $n$, you can calculate $g(C(k)-n)$ for some *small* $k$ and then append a bunch of `()()()` onto the beginning of the result. I think you'd better edit your question to explain in more detail what you are doing.

Comment: Done. Hope everything's clear now. Sorry.

Comment: No, not at all.  Suppose you are calculating balanced strings of 1000 pairs of parentheses.  Now maybe you only want the first very few such strings, say up to the 1000000th or the $2^{32}$th or whatever. In that case you can pretend that you are generating strings of **20** pairs of balanced paretheses, that have `()()…()` appended 980 times on the end.  Or you are calculating strings from far along the list, in which case you need to use bignums anyway.  So what is the problem exactly?  Have you thought this through?

Comment: I don't know if that's few but I have to calculate up to $10^{18}$th string. So bignums are not necessary, but I don't know how to calculate the number of () at the end or the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some study of the material from Ruskey’s thesis, I was able to come up with the following algorithm more or less in the style of Knuth’s version. I don’t guarantee its correctness; minor programming errors are certainly possible. I have, however, included an example on which it works correctly. I haven’t the facilities to code the algorithm and test it more extensively, so I’d appreciate feedback if you try it.

> 1. Set $p\leftarrow 0,c\leftarrow 1$. While $p<n-2$, set $p\leftarrow p+1,c\leftarrow\dfrac{2(2p-1)}{p+1}c$.
> 2. Set $q\leftarrow n,c\leftarrow\dfrac{6(p+1)(2p+1)}{(p+2)(p+3)}c$.
> 3. Set $a_1=\text{'('},m\leftarrow 2$.
> 4. If $m>2n$, stop.
> 5. If $p<0$, set $a_m\leftarrow\text{')'},m\leftarrow m+1$ and return to step (4).
> 6. If $N\le c$, set $a_m\leftarrow \text{'('},m\leftarrow m+1,p\leftarrow p-1,c\leftarrow\dfrac{(p+1)(q-p+1)}{(q+p+1)(q-p)}c$, and return to step (4).
> 7. Set $a_m\leftarrow \text{')'},m\leftarrow m+1,N\leftarrow N-c,q\leftarrow q-1,c\leftarrow \dfrac{(q-p+1)(q+2)}{(q+p+1)(q-p+2)}c$. If $q-p<2$, set $a_m\leftarrow\text{'('},m\leftarrow m+1,p\leftarrow p-1,c\leftarrow\dfrac{(p+1)(q-p+1)}{(q+p+1)(q-p)}c$, and return to step (4).

**Example:** Take $n=4,N=6$.

$$\begin{array}{c}
N&m&a&p&q&c\\ \hline
6&&&0&&1\\
6&&&1&&1\\
6&&&2&&2\\
6&&&2&4&9\\
6&2&\text{(}&2&4&9\\
6&3&\text{(}&1&4&4\\
2&4&\text{)}&1&3&3\\
2&5&\text{(}&0&3&1\\
1&6&\text{)}&0&2&1\\
1&7&\text{(}&-1&2&0\\
1&8&\text{)}&-1&2&0\\
1&9&\text{)}&-1&2&0
\end{array}$$

The output string is $\text{(()()())}$, exactly as it should be.

**Added:** Here’s a brief explanation of the algorithm. Let $C(q,p)$ be the number of Dyck paths (allowing only steps down or to the left and not crossing the diagonal) from $\langle q,p\rangle$ to the origin; $C(n,n)$ is simply $C_n$, the $n$-th Catalan number. A balanced string of $2n$ parentheses corresponds to a Dyck path from $\langle n,n\rangle$ to the origin: each '(' correponds to a down-step and each ')' to a left-step. When such a path reaches $\langle q,p\rangle$, there are still $C(q,p)$ ways to complete the string. Here’s a table of $C(q,p)$ for $0\le p\le q\le 4$, since I’ll use the case $n=4$ for illustration.

$$\begin{array}{c|rr}
p\backslash q&0&1&2&3&4\\ \hline
4&&&&&14\\
3&&&&5&14\\
2&&&2&5&9\\
1&&1&2&3&4\\
0&1&1&1&1&1
\end{array}$$

We start at $\langle 4,4\rangle$, with $14$ possible strings. The first symbol must be '(', so the first step must be a downstep, to $\langle 4,3\rangle$; of course any of the $14$ strings is still possible, and indeed $C(4,3)=14$. Now, though, there are two possibilities. If the second symbol is also '(', there are still $C(4,2)=9$ ways to complete the string, but if it’s ')', there are only $C(3,2)=5$. There’s an important difference, though. The $5$ strings that are eliminated when the second symbol is '(' are all later in the lexicographic order than any string that is still possible. The $9$ strings that are eliminated when the second symbol is ')', however, **precede** all of the strings that remain possible. Thus, if we’re trying to construct one of the first $9$ strings, we cannot have ')' as the second symbol and cannot take a left-step to $\langle 3,2\rangle$.

What we’d really like is a table showing how many earlier possibilities are eliminated at each left-step, i.e.,  when we generate a ')'. For the case $n=4$ we can simply build the table from the one above:

$$\begin{array}{c|rr}
p\backslash q&0&1&2&3&4\\ \hline
4&&&&&\cdot\\
3&&&&9&\cdot\\
2&&&3&4&\cdot\\
1&&1&1&1&\cdot\\
0&0&0&0&0&\cdot
\end{array}$$

It’s immediately apparent that this is the lower righthand corner of the previous table, with an extra row of zeroes at the bottom. If I denote these numbers by $e(q,p)=C(q+1,p)-C(q,p)$, it appears that $e(q,p)=C(q+1,p-1)$.

This is not hard to prove. It’s clear from the definition that $C(q,p)=C(q,p-1)+C(q-1,p)$ whenever $q,p>0$, so in that case we have

$$e(q,p)=C(q+1,p)-C(q,p)=\Big(C(q+1,p-1)+C(q,p)\Big)-C(q,p)=C(q+1,p-1)\;.$$

If you want one of the first $9$ strings, you can’t afford to eliminate the first $9$, so you can’t take the left-step from $\langle 4,3\rangle$ to $\langle 3,3\rangle$. If you want the $11$-th string, you **must** get past the first $9$, so you **must** take that left-step. At that point you’re on the diagonal, so you can’t take a left-step; you have to take a down-step. Now you’re at $\langle 3,2\rangle$, and the $e$-table indicates that a left-step will eliminate another $3$ strings. That’s too many $-$ you want the $11$-string, not the $13$-th or $14$-th $-$ so you take another down-step, to $\langle 3,1\rangle$. Now a left-step eliminates only one string, for a total of $9+1=10$ strings eliminated, so you take it and land at $\langle 2,1\rangle$. You have now eliminated (or gone past) $10$ strings, so you’re at the $11$-th string and must not eliminate any more. That forces you to take the down-step to $\langle 2,0\rangle$, and at that point you just run out the strong with closing parentheses until you have $2n$ symbols.

I’ve used $q$ and $p$ here exactly as they are used in my algorithm. At step (2) $c$ is initialized to $C(n,n-2)=e(n-1,n-1)$. Step (3) generates the leading '('. Step (5) tests the current partial string to see whether it’s balanced; if it is, the next symbol must be '('. Step (6) handles the case in which a left-step would eliminate too many strings, so I must take a down-step by making the next symbol a '('; $p$ is decreased by $1$ to take the down-step, and $C(q,p)$ is updated accordingly. Step (7) handles the other possibility, that I need to take a left-step in order to reach my desired string; it generates the associated ')', decreases $q$ by one to take the left-step, updates $C(q,p)$, and subtracts the number of strings eliminated from my target number $N$, so that I know how many remain to be eliminated.

The formulas for updating $C(q,p)$ are essentially equations $(9)$ and $(10)$ from page 19 of Ruskey’s thesis.

Comment: It works. :D Thanks. Here's a program with which You can check some smaller inputs: https://ideone.com/2AUwx . And here's one for reverse algorithm: https://ideone.com/vKiMm . And a question - to understand Your algorithm I have to read all PNGs from my link or just some (which)?

Comment: @user39042: Pages $16,17$,$20$-$22$, and equations $(9)$ and $(10)$ on page $19$ were the ones most useful to me. If I can find the time, I’ll try to add some explanatory notes to my answer in the next day or two.

Comment: @user39042: Okay, I’ve added some explanation. You’ll probably have to play with it a bit, but I think that I’ve said enough to make it possible to see how the algorithm works. Let me know if you have any questions.